# Can an Android library project produce APKs?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have a working Android tuner project app that I want to use as a library. The problem is the moment I mark it as a library (`Project Properties` -> `Android` -> `Is Library`) it suddenly can't run and I get this error message:

```
[2011-09-04 19:25:31 - androidtuner] Could not find androidtuner.apk!
```

Things I've tried:

1. Read through the reference
   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html
2. Cleaned my project, rebuilt everything
3. Closing Eclipse and reopening
4. Deleting the project from eclipse and importing it back.

Is a library Android project just not meant to be executable?

edit - the project for reference - http://code.google.com/p/androidtuner/source/browse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a library android project just not meant to be executable?

Correct. The idea of a library is to be a set of shared code and/or resources, and to reference it from other projects so you don't duplicate them.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

> You can also designate an Android project as a library project,
>   which allows it to be shared with other projects that depend on it.
>   Once an Android project is designated as a library project, it cannot
>   be installed onto a device.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I don't see a problem with a library sharing code and/or resources while being a self-reliant app as well.

Comment: How embarrassing to miss the second line of that big page. Thank you.